# Xcode won't upload flutter project to App Store

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have an iOS app created with flutter, and have just paid my $99 to apple to upload it to the App Store. I've created the app archive, but in the Organizer Upload to App Store… is grayed out, and I've got "Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple Developer Program."[Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple Developer Program image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VldsS.png)

[IOS provisioning profile expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S9JK.png)

[signing certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrkgS.png)

Comment: First of all the certificate is wrong. You can't sign a release build with a ```developer``` certificate, you need a ```distribution``` certificate. For the first error, it's possible that apple needs some time to process your payment. Also are you able to connect to ```https://developer.apple.com/```.

Comment: yes i can connect to https://developer.apple.com/...but  how do i can convert it to distribution certificate.

Comment: Have a look over this one: https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003458931-Creating-the-iOS-Distribution-Certificate. There are many tutorials on the web on how to sign the app for App Store.